# what is missing in my java immediate initialization?

Tags: java, android

I have created two custom java DTO classes

I try to initialize both of them but get an error

..

```
PeriodicDataToServer pData = new PeriodicDataToServer(){

    location = new Location() {
        longtitude ="", latitude = "";
    };
}
```

..

```
public class PeriodicDataToServer {
    public Location location;
}


public class Location {

    public String longtitude;
    public String latitude;

}
```

..

**Errors:**

```
Syntax error on token "location", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Syntax error on token "longtitude", } expected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
PeriodicDataToServer pData = new PeriodicDataToServer() {{

    location = new Location() {{
        longtitude ="", latitude = "";
    }};
}};
```

This is a trick I liked too, but it has a large drawback: it creates anonymous classes.

For other readers:

```
class A { int n; }

 A a = new A() {{ n = 3; }};
```

has an inner initialisation block `{ n = 3; }`, like in:

```
class B {
    int[] a = new int[2};
    {
        a[0] = 12;
        a[1] = 34;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PeriodicDataToServer pData = new PeriodicDataToServer(){

    location = new Location() { // this is not possible.
        longtitude ="", latitude = "";
    };
}; // <- this semicolon was missing
```

you are using anonymous classes here. what you are trying is initializing fields in javascript notation!

but you can use initialization blocks (which is a very bad style):

```
PeriodicDataToServer pData = new PeriodicDataToServer() {

    { // this is the init block for PeriodicDataToServer
        Location location = new Location() {
            { // this is the init block for Location
                longtitude ="", latitude = "";
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: same error: `Syntax error on token "location", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token` and `Syntax error on token "longtitude", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`